# 3 state Toggle Button in Access Form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, togglebutton

Is it possible to create a Toggle Button inside of an Access Form which has **more than two** "states"/Options?

I'm creating a calendar with a monthly view which is composed of Toggle Buttons. The user should be able to click the toggle buttons in order to indicate if he is:

1. Available
2. Not Available
3. On Holiday

I therefore need a Toggle Button capable of 3 or more states/options.

If you have any alternative ideas to a Toggle Button method I would be very grateful.

---

As an idea of what my calendar looks like with toggle buttons here is a picture of my form:

[image]

Comment: Why toggle buttons?  Why not use a grouping of radio buttons?

Comment: I hadn't considered using radio buttons, but I'm still looking for a UI which looks like the picture above. If I can't find any alternatives, i suppose I'll resort to radio buttons. Ultimately though, I would maintain this format so that user can understand it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Tom's approach with label controls for Access 2007.  The procedure below made it easy to use each label's click event to toggle between green, yellow, and red.

Call the procedure like this for each of the labels.

```
Private Sub Label16_Click()
    ToggleColor Me.Label16
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleColor(ByRef lbl As Label)
    Dim lngColor As Long
    Dim strPrompt As String

    If lbl.BackStyle = 0 Then ' Transparent
        strPrompt = "BackColor will not be displayed when " & _
            "BackStyle is Transparent." & vbCrLf & _
            "Change " & lbl.Name & " BackStyle property to Normal."
        MsgBox strPrompt, vbExclamation
    Else
        Select Case lbl.BackColor
        Case vbGreen
            lngColor = vbYellow
        Case vbYellow
            lngColor = vbRed
        Case vbRed
            lngColor = vbGreen
        Case Else
            lngColor = vbGreen
        End Select
        lbl.BackColor = lngColor
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample of how to do it. You can modify it to accept a button reference to use the code for many buttons.

Also, it turns out this only works for Access 2010+. If using a version before 2010, you can use a label as a button instead.

```
Private Sub Btn_Click()
    Select Case Me.Btn.BackColor
      Case &HFF
         Me.Btn.BackColor = &HFF00
      Case &HFF00
         Me.Btn.BackColor = &HFF0000
      Case Else
         Me.Btn.BackColor = &HFF
   End Select
End Sub
```

This will cycle through the three possible states. I used different colors, but you can really use anything.

Comment: What type of control did you intend for `Btn`?  With `Btn` as either a toggle or command button, Access 2007 gives me a compile error (Method or data member not found) with `.BackColor`.  Do you have this working in a newer Access version?

Comment: I used a command button in Access 2010. I thought Access 2007 had a backcolor property for their command buttons as well, but on searching, I find this to not be true. An alternative would be to use a label instead.

Comment: The `.BackColor` property does work if you use an ActiveX toggle button or command button in Access 2007. I am not able to set the backColor however. I will look into this further though.